# How do I generate a list of one-time passwords?

Tags: php, web, authentication, passwords, one-time-password

I am currently working on a website for which I would need to create a password-protected section. The passwords should be single-use only, turning unusable after being entered successfully.

OTP seems to be the way to go, but I can't find guides on generating lists of passwords for the OTP, just ones that teach how to send SMS or use a separate software.

The security of the website doesn't have to be hacker-proof, just secure enough that the average person doesn't know how to abuse it.

Comment: There are many ways to accomplish this.. You can try using PHP's random integer generate functions and then store that random number in database against the record you want to... Then use a flag to check if it has been used or not..Read this from Database.. it is quite easy

Answer (score 0):

You could create a column such as 'used' that you set a value to 'yes' on logging in the first time. The logic of your code to check if password is valid would need to use this column to determine if the user can login.

Answer (score 0):

Here is PHP (not OTP specific) code that will generate a random password based on parameters that you specify:

```
<?php

//variables
$minimumASCIIValue = 33;
$maximumASCIIValue = 126;
$generatedPassword = "";
$numberOfCharacters = 12;

//code
for($i = 0; $i < $numberOfCharacters; $i++)
{
    $generatedPassword = $generatedPassword . chr((rand($minimumASCIIValue,$maximumASCIIValue)));
}

//output
echo "The generated one-time password is " . $generatedPassword;

?>
```

Example output:

> The generated one-time password is %J7%L)50$A*X